What is the meaning of $\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)$?
According to Wikipedia the Breit operator is given by
$$
\hat{B}_{i j}=-\frac{1}{2 r_{i j}}\left[\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)+\frac{\left(\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)\left(\vec{\alpha}(j) \cdot \mathbf{r}_{i j}\right)}{r_{i j}^2}\right]
$$
what is the meaning of $\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)$?
Is it $\vec{\alpha}(i) \cdot \vec{\alpha}(j)=\alpha_1(i)\otimes\alpha_1(j)+\alpha_2(i)\otimes\alpha_2(j)+\alpha_3(i)\otimes\alpha_3(j)$

Basically, yes. The Dirac matrix of the $i$-th electron (in an $N$-electron system) is an $N$-fold Kronecker product:
\begin{equation}
 \alpha_a(i)=I_4\otimes I_4\otimes...\otimes\underbrace{\alpha_a}_{\text{$i$-th factor}}\otimes...\otimes I_4 \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_a$ is the usual $4\times4$ Dirac matrix, $I_4$ is the $4\times4$ unit matrix, and $a=1,2,3$ is a cartesian index. The identity matrices simply mean that $\vec{\alpha}(i)$ acts only on the Hilbert space of the $i$-th electron. Then
\begin{align}
 \vec{\alpha}(i)\cdot\vec{\alpha}(j)&=\sum_{a=1}^3\alpha_a(i)\alpha_a(j) \\
&=\sum_{a=1}^3I_4\otimes I_4\otimes...\otimes\underbrace{\alpha_a}_{\text{$i$-th factor}}\otimes...\otimes\underbrace{\alpha_a}_{\text{$j$-th factor}}\otimes...\otimes I_4 \ .
\end{align}
